# How to initialize UIView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to just initialize UIView for table footer in swift like in objective c

```
_searchTableView.tableFooterView =[[UIView alloc] init];
```

to remove tableview separator lines How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh just end up by.

```
_searchTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

With frame

```
 _searchTableView.tableFooterView  = UIView (frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `initialize` by following ways.

1)Without Frame

```
self.searchTableView.tableFooterView = UIView ()
```

2) With Frame.

```
self.searchTableView.tableFooterView = UIView (frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks was looking for without frame.